# iPhone 6 charging problem

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to plug my phone in to charge it tonight for the first time and when I plug it in a bell just keeps ringing continuously and won't allow me to charge it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad cable / USB adapter / power outlet. Maybe lint on the Lightning socket.

Does the battery icon alternate between charging / standby or anything else on the screen change with the tempo of the sounds?

Three things are needed to charge:

- USB power adapter
- USB to lightning cable
- Phone internals / charge circuitry working correctly

It's probably easiest to plug the cable and phone into any other USB charger or USB hub or USB computer. If the problem follows the cable or the phone - you'll need a different phone or a different cable to know what's faulty.

Worst case, put the phone in airplane mode (or power it off) and you'll hardly lose any change over night. It won't top off, but you can take it to another charger/cable in the morning or find another phone to test with your charger and cable.

Comment: forgive the large edit. Your answer is spot on, just had a bit to add.